# Laravel Eloquent: Rename fields only in Model Class

Tags: laravel, eloquent, field, naming-conventions, alias

I have a table that have many fields that have a bad names and containes much  underscores "_"
I want to rename them (or give them alias) only in the class, not in the table it self, because this table is used by other application so I don't to do changes in the database.

This an example of what I want:

What I have:

```
$model->foo_bar_wtf_man
```

What I want:

```
$model->fooBarWtfMan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't call having `_` in db names bad, but here's the easy way:

```
// BaseModel extending Eloquent\Model, then other models extend BaseModel
public function __get($key)
{
    return (parent::__get($key)) ?: parent::__get(snake_case($key));
}
```

Then you can do:

```
// either
$foo->bar_baz_wtf;
// or
$foo->barBazWtf;
```

That's generic solution. If you want to handle 'bad names' as well, then you need **accessors** for each one of them.